# Relative benefits of systemd and update-rc.d for boot scripting

Tags: boot, systemd, startup

I've been using [update-rc.d](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-managing-services-with-update-rc-d/) to get scripts to run on startup on Yocto, which lacks an `/etc/rc.local` file.  Now I've just come across [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd), which appears to do exactly the same thing.  Can anyone clarify if these work in different ways or are they pretty much the same thing?